# How to pause and restart scraper

Tags: python, scrapy

Jobdir is what takes care of all the visited sites and it doesnt visit them again.

```
class Myspider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'spidername'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_1.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_2.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_3.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_4.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_5.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_6.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_7.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_8.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_9.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_10.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_11.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_12.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_13.xml']

    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/otomobil/', 'parse'),

    ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_FORMAT':'csv','FEED_URI': "arabam_"+str(datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%y'))+'.csv',
                       'JOBDIR': './job'


   }
```

But the problem is that it adds these start urls to job as well and when the scraper is restarted it doesnt run at all because start urls are already visited. How do I take care of this ?

Comment: You want to resume but re-download the `sitemap_urls`?

Comment: yes...that's exactly what's needed

Comment: Then you would probably have to edit the files created at `JOBDIR` to remove those URLs.

Comment: how do I do that????????

Comment: I’m not familiar with the format of its content, and it is not covered in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html so it’s rather a hack. But if you check the files generated inside the `JOBDIR` folder and you can figure out where those URLs are added causing Scrapy not to crawl them again, you should be able to remove them. It’s a wild guess, though, I have not tried this myself.